# Arbitrarily many stationary distributions of a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> Consider the following Markov chain on $\{-1, 0, 1\}$. In each step of
> the Markov chain we flip a coin $Y \in\{0, 1\}$ and a coin $Z\in \{+1,
> > -1\}$ and set $X_{n+1} = X_n +Y\cdot Z\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X_n=0\}}$. Show that $(X_n)_n$ has arbitrarily many stationary distributions.

I played a bit with the Markov chain. I don't get how there can be the "arbitrarly many" stationary distributions. Suppose you reached a point where some $X_n\neq 0$, than we have a stationary distribution because $Y\cdot Z\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X_n=0\}}$ will always be $0$ regardless of $Y$ and $Z$. There are two possibilities for $X_n$ to be nonzero, i. e. $-1$ and $1$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Should that  be "$Z\in\{+1,-1\}$"?)

If so, then because the states $+1$ and $-1$ are absorbing, for each $p\in[0,1]$ the distribution that puts weight $p$ at $+1$ and weight $1-p$ at $-1$ (and no weight at $0$) is stationary.